# Video over network - compression

Tags: c++, video, tcp, stream

I'm streaming video over tcp/ip using C++ with winsocket/escapi. Everything is working well, despite the extremely big network traffic. The video is 320x240 32bit, so thats quite too much to have at least 15fps (thats what Im aiming at). Each frame is sent in a single tcp packet. I'd like to compress the data to send, and then decompress it later, after its receieved.

I have read this article: http://binfalse.de/2011/04/comparison-of-compression/, but it compares algorithms on big data pieces, and my packets are small... Im pretty sure those algorithms behaveiour is different in my case.

What is the best algorithm to compress **small ammount of semi-random data**?

Video compression (or any frame-differencial algorithms) are out of play, I just need to stream it frame by frame.

General ideas are enough, but the C++ snippets or some pseudocode would be great.

Thank you for any answers :)

Comment: You'll have to test different algorithms on your data. You probably don't want to compress each frame completely individually -- you'll probably want stream compression because the compression will be better.

Comment: Stream compression would be hell too complicated for 2 file project - its also much harder to implement. I bet its possible to have steady 320x240 @ 15fps with image only compression.

Comment: What is the desired data loss rate or sum of squares of errors of rgb values?

Comment: One frame per packet?  320x240x32-bits is way too much for one packet.  Do you mean that you are hoping to achieve that?

Comment: Why is 320x240x32 too much? I thought that TCP don't care at all and cuts it into pieces anyway...

Comment: @kittyPL I think they're trying to figure out what you meant by "Each frame is sent in a single tcp packet." Usually people who say things like that don't understand that TCP doesn't preserve application message boundaries.

Comment: @kittyPL: those pieces are called packets.

Comment: Oh, thats true. Retransmiting those big packets may take a while. Haven't thought about it, my bad. Im quite sleppy tho and I need to have this finished by tomorrow :/

Comment: How about making a jpeg or png for each frame?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jpeg-compressor/ - Should that be enough?